# how to directly render to MP4 for Adobe After Effects

Tags: animation, adobe, mp4

We all know that in Adobe After Effects, compositing does not support direct rendering to MP4, but many animation effects on mobile phones are implemented in MP4

Comment: Use your SO account to ask at: [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/). Also not obvious what happens when you try to export as MP4. I've been exporting MP4 from After Effects for over 10 years. Explain your attempt when you ask there...

Answer (score 0):

Render your After Effects project as MP4 by adding files to the render queue and then designating Media Encoder as the renderer.

In the output settings, designate MP4 as the file type.  You will also have options for compression settings and bitrate.